# Filter result by using global php value in views

Tags: 7, views

I am appending city code and city value in global php field in views

Now I want to filter the result based on this field value.

For example if a record having city code:NY and city:New York If i search NY-New York then it should filter the results.

Any help plz..

Comment: did you tried grouping fields of code and city in views?

Comment: Yes displaying..lets simple..I want add filter for global php field in views?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. But try creating a view with grouped fields as "Code" and "City", then simply bind with token filter and output the result as replacements pattern. Tell me if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, using views filters change the SQL query, by adding a where clause in the SQL query. The limitation by this is that information needs to be in the database. Since the global PHP field doesn't exist in the database, it's not possible to use views filter on such a value.

You could write some code in a custom module, where you implement the logic and removes all unwanted records, but this wont perform well.

Generally you should avoid the global PHP fields if at all possible.